# Удалить все вхождения элементов в списке

Tags: python

Есть список:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1', '5', '4']
```

И есть другой список:

```
b = ['1', '3', '2']
```

Как из списка a удалить все элементы списка b?

Пробовала так, но удаляется только первый элемент:

```
for i in b:
    a.remove(i)
```

P.S.удалять надо не дубликаты, а только все вхождения элементов списка b в список а. то есть должен в итоге получиться список

```
['4', '5', '5', '4']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементарное **списковое включение** вполне работает, непонятно, в чём у вас сложность:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1', '5', '4']
b = ['1', '3', '2']
c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
print(c)
# ['4', '5', '5', '4']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1', '5', '4']
b = ['1', '3', '2']
print(list(filter(lambda x: x not in b, a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно было добавить проверку на то, что в списке `a` всё ещё есть элемент для удаления, и завернуть всё это дело в цикл `while`:

```py
for i in b:
    while i in a: # пока элемент i есть в a,
        a.remove(i) # убираем i из a
```